# OAuth 'oauth2-token' endpoint returns HTML not JSON

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm following the documentation in regards to generating an Access Token using OAuth Client Credentials flow, [from the following link](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth-client-credentials/). However, on providing the below HTTP POST request, it returns a HTML body of a login page and not the expected JSON response containing the Access Token. It appears to be the correct end-point, because I receive a HTML page of a 405 error when using GET method instead - which is expected, aside from it returning in HTML as well.

Is this a known issue, or am I going wrong somewhere?

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://example.com/oauth2-token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxx"
}
```

Furthermore, the API is enabled in the configuration, and the initialization of the OAuth with generating an encryption key has also been completed.

OroCommerce is running 4.1.1 on CentOS with Nginx (via Azure Marketplace)

Comment: What application and the version do you use?

Comment: I'm running OroCommerce version 4.1.1 - I'll update the OP to include this. The API request was made using Postman.

Comment: I found a bug. When you have guest access disabled - the API is not available and it returns an HTML of a login page. Do you have guest access enabled (https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/guests/#guest-website-access)?

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I've disabled it, and as you say it's working normally now! Annoyingly we need the Guest Mode disabled. But we can get away with temporarily disabling it for now to enable execution of our program. Is there somewhere I can track the issue please?

Comment: If you are using a community edition, please create a bug report on GitHub to track the progress. https://github.com/oroinc/platform/issues/new/choose. Thank you!

Comment: Super, will do - thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Andrey Yatsenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735724/andrey-yatsenko) above, this issue is caused by a bug from disabling "Guest Mode" in System -> Configuration -> Guest Mode. The API is returning the login page from guest mode being disabled. By enabling Guest Mode, the end-point returns the JSON as expected.