# Fetching bearer token for OroCommerce returning error 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: orocommerce

I'm attempting to fetch the bearer token for OroCommerce, via POSTMAN and am encountering a 405 error, for the following request:

URL: `http://<OroCommerce DNS>/oauth2-token`

Header: `Content-Type: application/json`

Body:

```
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "XXXX",
    "client_secret": "XXXX"
}
```

I have generated the public and private keys and added them to the /var directory of the application. Per [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878730/oauth-oauth2-token-endpoint-returns-html-not-json?rq=1), I have tried "Enabled Guest Access" checked and unchecked. Both result in the same 405 error w/ HTML in the response (see image below). The back-end is up, when attempting these requests. Any suggestions on where to look (configurations, etc), in order to successfully fetch the bearer token, via the REST API?

**Response HTML**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, make sure an API is enabled: https://doc.oroinc.com/api/enabling-api-feature/.
2. Then, make sure you are using the POST HTTP method to submit the request.
3. If it wouldn't help, make sure the maintenance mode is fully disabled. It's step 13 in the upgrade guide: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/upgrade-to-new-version/#id1
4. Check the application log at `var/logs/prod.log` for errors. Usually, the error message explains what is wrong, or at least, you can use it to google the issue.
5. If nothing works, you can try to access the same endpoint using the `dev` environment. There should be a more explicit error message with the stack trace. Or enable an xdebug extension and check it step by step.

Comment: Andrey, thanks for following up. I verified the API is enabled (#1) and the request is POST (#2). When attempting to unlock maintenance mode (#3) via the following:

`php74 bin/console lexik:maintenance:unlock --env=prod`

I receive the following warning and message:

You are about to unlock your server.  
WARNING! Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n) y
Impossible to do this action.

Comment: Checking the production log (#4) shows the following when issuing the POST request:  

[2021-02-16 14:00:46] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: "No route found for "GET /oauth2-token": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST, OPTIONS)" at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 140 {"exception":"[object] ...

Comment: and: 
[2021-02-16 14:00:46] request.ERROR: Can't render layout template, because of errors in some layout templates {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []

Comment: Via the Postman console, I verified a POST is sent to <my OroCommerce DNS>/oauth2-token. However, the logs indicate a GET request was received. Could this be a redirect on the server-side?

Comment: It might be the redirect on the webserver (e.g. nginx) side, but there is nothing like that on the application side.

Comment: Update: I am able to successfully fetch the bearer token using the IP address. But switching to the DNS, produces the above error, in the log. Is there additional configuration required to access the `/oauth2-token` endpoint, via DNS? I used the AWS Marketplace for setup.